# I have a path that's a variable and a generic filename, how do I tell applescript to replace the generic filename with New_Name

Tags: applescript

EDIT:

It's working nowm this is the final script:

```
tell application "Finder"

display dialog "new_name_dialogue" default answer " "

set new_name to (text returned of result)

set Selected_Finder_Item to (folder of the front window) as text

duplicate file "Macintosh HD:x:7:n7:GTD scripting:template folder:x.txt" to Selected_Finder_Item

set Path_Of_X to Selected_Finder_Item & "x.txt" as string

set name of file Path_Of_X to (new_name as text) & ".txt"
end tell
```

I have a variable that is a path, it's called Selected_Finder_Item. I also have a generic file, x.txt, that's duplicated into Selected_Finder_Item. How do I make changing the name of x.txt to the variable new_name a part of the script?

This is my script:

```
tell application "Finder"

display dialog "new_name_dialogue" default answer " "

set new_name to (text returned of result)

set Selected_Finder_Item to (folder of the front window) as text

duplicate file "Macintosh HD:x:7:n7:GTD scripting:template folder:x.txt" to Selected_Finder_Item
[HERE I NEED SOMETHING THAT CHANGES THE FILE NAME OF "Selected_Finder_Item"+"x.txt" TO "new_name"]

end tell
```

I can't make it work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...

```
set the name of Selected_Finder_Item to new_name
```

**UPDATE:** To set multiple variables to one variable, do something like this:

```
set a to {b, c, d}
```

Comment: thanks for answering! but, this would only turn ONE variable into another, my problem is (I think) that I can't make an ad hoc variable out of (1) the destination folder and (2) the generically named txt file. The path that's (1) and the filename that's (2) should be enough info to change the name of the txt file, but I can't make it work. Will add some new info in an edit above.